# Remote push notification doesn't wake up app

Tags: ios, push-notification, xamarin.ios, apple-push-notifications

We use remote push notification with content available = 1, as per document it will wake up app, but it doesn't work properly, sometimes the app doesn't wake up.

I have observed this behaviour mostly on iOS 15.

We use this mechanism to send device location to our server.

Why remote push notification doesn't wake up my app all the time ?

Comment: Content available pushes are throttled. https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotifications/setting_up_a_remote_notification_server/pushing_background_updates_to_your_app. The more frequently you use it the more likely you are to be throttled

Comment: The problem had been put forward for a long time. It seems that if the user has force-quit it, the push notification can't wake up the app. You can check this [link](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/8564).

Comment: Same issue with .Net Maui iOS app and iOS 16. This is so frustrating!!!

Comment: @Anish Vartak did you ever figure this out or come up with a different solution for location tracking?